# How can I run JMH benchmarking operations for Average runtime metrics?

Tags: java, testing, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I am trying to measure average runtime performance for particular methods. I want to run them 100 million times. With default options this is taking an eternity. What options I can enable or disable to achieve a faster execution time for the benchmark testing as a whole? I do not need warm up and other fine tuning. All I need is average time for 100 million operations.

Answer (score -1):

We can set

```java
@Measurement(iterations = 100000000)
public void function() {
    // ...
}
```

to have the JMH execute your operation 100 million times.

Comment: you also need to have the mode as `Mode.SingleShotTime`